# Mismatch in batch size

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

**My complete code is here: I am following github code for accomplishing my task. I am getting dimensions mismatch error. The code is giving me dimension mismatch error. I am receiving the following error: ValueError: Expected input batch_size (1) to match target batch_size (64).I am confused, i don't know what should i change in this code. Please help me in resolving this issue. **

```
def windowz(data, size):
   start = 0
   while start < len(data):
       yield start, start + size
      start += (size // 2)


 def segment_pa2(x_train,y_train,window_size):
segments = np.zeros(((len(x_train)//(window_size//2))-1,window_size,52))
labels = np.zeros(((len(y_train)//(window_size//2))-1))
i_segment = 0
i_label = 0
for (start,end) in windowz(x_train,window_size):
    if(len(x_train[start:end]) == window_size):
        m = stats.mode(y_train[start:end])
        segments[i_segment] = x_train[start:end]
        labels[i_label] = m[0]
        i_label+=1
        i_segment+=1

  return segments, labels
  print ('starting...')
 start_time = time.time()

dataset = sys.argv[1]
 path = '/Users/tehreem/Desktop/PAMAP2/PAMAP2_Dataset/pamap2.h5'

f = h5py.File(path, 'r')
print(f)

   x_train = f.get('train').get('inputs')[()]
   y_train = f.get('train').get('targets')[()]

  x_test = f.get('test').get('inputs')[()]
  y_test = f.get('test').get('targets')[()]


 print ("x_train shape =",x_train.shape)
 print ("y_train shape =",y_train.shape)
 print ("x_test shape =" ,x_test.shape)
 print ("y_test shape =",y_test.shape)


x_train = x_train[::3,:]
y_train = y_train[::3]
x_test = x_test[::3,:]
y_test = y_test[::3]
print ("x_train shape(downsampled) = ", x_train.shape)
print ("y_train shape(downsampled) =",y_train.shape)
print ("x_test shape(downsampled) =" ,x_test.shape)
print ("y_test shape(downsampled) =",y_test.shape)

 print (np.unique(y_train))
 print (np.unique(y_test))
unq = np.unique(y_test)

input_width = 52
print("segmenting signal...")
train_x, train_y = segment_pa2(x_train,y_train,input_width)
test_x, test_y = segment_pa2(x_test,y_test,input_width)
print ("signal segmented.")

train = pd.get_dummies(train_y)
test = pd.get_dummies(test_y)
train, test = train.align(test, join='inner', axis=1)

train_y = np.asarray(train)
test_y = np.asarray(test)

input_height = 1
input_width = input_width 
num_labels = 11  
num_channels = 52 

   batch_size = 64
   stride_size = 2
   kernel_size_1 = 7
  kernel_size_2 = 3
  kernel_size_3 = 1
  depth_1 = 128
 depth_2 = 128
depth_3 = 128
num_hidden = 512 

 dropout_1 = 0.1 #0.1
 dropout_2 = 0.25 #0.25
 dropout_3 = 0.5 #0.5

learning_rate = 0.0005
training_epochs = 50
total_batches = train_x.shape[0] // batch_size


  train_x = train_x.reshape(len(train_x),1,input_width,num_channels) 
  test_x = test_x.reshape(len(test_x),1,input_width,num_channels) 
 print ("test_x_reshaped = " , test_x.shape)
 print ("train_x shape =",train_x.shape)
 print ("train_y shape =",train_y.shape)
 print ("test_x shape =",test_x.shape)
 print ("test_y shape =",test_y.shape)

 train_x = train_x.reshape(-1,input_width,num_channels) 
 test_x = test_x.reshape(-1,input_width,num_channels) 

 def init_weights(m):
if type(m) == nn.LSTM:
    for name, param in m.named_parameters():
        if 'weight_ih' in name:
            torch.nn.init.orthogonal_(param.data)
        elif 'weight_hh' in name:
            torch.nn.init.orthogonal_(param.data)
        elif 'bias' in name:
            param.data.fill_(0)
  elif type(m) == nn.Conv1d or type(m) == nn.Linear:
    torch.nn.init.orthogonal_(m.weight)
    m.bias.data.fill_(0)
 model.apply(init_weights) 

 import torch
 import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

  class  CharCNN(nn.Module):
     def __init__(self):
     super(CharCNN, self).__init__()

    self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv1d(num_channels, depth_1, kernel_size=kernel_size_1, stride=stride_size),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=kernel_size_1, stride=stride_size),
        nn.Dropout(0.1),
    )

    self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv1d(depth_1, depth_2, kernel_size=kernel_size_2, stride=stride_size),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=kernel_size_2, stride=stride_size),
        nn.Dropout(0.25)
    )            


    self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(128*64, num_hidden),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Dropout(0.5)
    )

    self.fc2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(num_hidden, 11),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Dropout(0.5)
    )



def forward(self, x):
    out = self.conv1(x)
    out = self.conv2(out)

    # collapse
    out = out.reshape(-1,128*64)
    #out = out.view(out.size(0), -1) 
    # linear layer
    out = self.fc1(out)
    # output layer
    out = self.fc2(out)
    #out = self.log_softmax(x,dim=1)

    return out

 model =  CharCNN()
 print(model)

def iterate_minibatches(inputs, targets, batch_size, shuffle=True):
assert len(inputs) == len(targets)
if shuffle:
    indices = np.arange(len(inputs))
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
for start_idx in range(0, len(inputs) - batch_size + 1, batch_size):
    if shuffle:
        excerpt = indices[start_idx:start_idx + batch_size]
    else:
        excerpt = slice(start_idx, start_idx + batch_size)
    yield inputs[excerpt], targets[excerpt]

 criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()    
opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=learning_rate)


for e in range(training_epochs):
   if(train_on_gpu):
     net.cuda()
   train_losses = []    

for batch in iterate_minibatches(train_x, train_y, batch_size):
    x, y = batch
    inputs, targets = torch.from_numpy(x), torch.from_numpy(y)
    if(train_on_gpu):
        inputs, targets = inputs.cuda(), targets.cuda()
        #inputs= inputs.view(batch_size,  128*64)
        #targets = targets.view(batch_size)
    opt.zero_grad()   
    output = model(inputs)

    loss = criterion(output, targets.long())
    train_losses.append(loss.item())
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
val_losses = []
accuracy=0
f1score=0
print("Epoch: {}/{}...".format(e+1, training_epochs),
              "Train Loss: {:.4f}...".format(np.mean(train_losses)))
```

**I received the following error:**

````
<ipython-input-468-7a508893b28d> in <module>
     21         output = model(inputs)
     22 
---> 23         loss = criterion(output, targets.long())
     24         train_losses.append(loss.item())
     25         loss.backward()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    530             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    531         else:
--> 532             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    533         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    534             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
    914     def forward(self, input, target):
    915         return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
--> 916                                ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
    917 
    918 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2019     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2020         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2021     return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
   2022 
   2023 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   1834     if input.size(0) != target.size(0):
   1835         raise ValueError('Expected input batch_size ({}) to match target batch_size ({}).'
-> 1836                          .format(input.size(0), target.size(0)))
   1837     if dim == 2:
   1838         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)

ValueError: Expected input batch_size (1) to match target batch_size (64).```
````

Comment: Can you also point out which line in your code is giving this error, and what the dimensions of your 'inputs', 'output', and 'targets' tensors are?

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-266-7a508893b28d> in <module>
     21         output = model(inputs)
     22 
---> 23         loss = criterion(output, targets.long())
     24         train_losses.append(loss.item())
     25         loss.backward()

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is giving me error in above line.

Comment: It would be really helpful in debugging if you can edit your question and mention the dimensions of the tensors I listed above, and also if you can add the entire error message as it is.

Comment: I edited my question and I posted my complete code and error message. Please help me in debugging the error in this code

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted hasn't been pasted correctly with proper indentations (it's different in every part of the code), so it's hard to go through the code.

But from what I understand from your error message, the problem lies with the size of your 'output' tensor. For a batch size of 64, the 'output' tensor should have the dimension (64, num_classes). But the first dimension of your 'output' tensor is 1 according to the error message. I suspect that there is an extra dimension getting added to your tensor somehow.

I would suggest printing out the size of your 'output' tensor using `output.size()` and that should give you an idea where the bug lies. If my intuition is correct and if it is indeed (1, 64, num_classes), then a simple `output = output.squeeze(0)` should do the trick.

Comment: When i print my output it gives the following output: torch.Size([1, 11]). This is without squeezing. What I understand from this is that my model is not taking the batch size properly. What should i change to fix this.

Comment: I created google colab file for my code. I think it will help in debugging my code
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QQ5NPvc6YjHncR-o3sdQfv7hzW3pGog3#scrollTo=vsHKBmFwI05T

Comment: You need to give public access to this colab link, otherwise I am unable to open it.

Comment: I have changed the permission. Please use this link. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QQ5NPvc6YjHncR-o3sdQfv7hzW3pGog3?usp=sharing

Comment: I went through your code. Since I didn't have access to the dataset, I couldn't actually run it and check, but here are a few things which I've noticed. Variable "stride_size" used in your conv and maxpool functions is not defined anywhere. So I am not quite sure how you are able to run even a forward prop correctly. And since I don't know what that is, I cannot compute the expected output size of your tensor just before the fully connected layers (I am not sure how you are getting 128 features after your 2 convolutional blocks even considering a stride size of 1 or 2).

Comment: Can you make sure that the input you are passing is of correct shape? i.e. (64, 52, 300). Other than that, I cannot find any obvious flaws in your code.